# How to import several sub-namespaces on PHP

Tags: php

I have this code

```
use App\Entities\Job;
use App\Entities\Category;
use App\Entities\City;
use App\Entities\JobType;

$viewModel['categories']= Category::all();
$viewModel['cities'] = City::all();
$viewModel['jobTypes'] = JobType::all();
```

I would like to avoid repetition and just put once something like `use App\Entities\*` and import all names behind `App\Entities`.

Usually on frameworks such as Laravel one may need to import many models or classes to work with them, and it would be easier if a generic `use` construct existed.

Comment: Thats not how namespaces work in php, your options are: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: So there is no way to do that without include all files?

Comment: No, you can just hide it in some IDE but you have to write them all.

Comment: Okey thanks for information. I will mark it like awnser if u post it like a awnser.

Comment: @ИванЖелев your question should be easier to find with a more appropriate title; and it's not specific to Laravel at all. As Steve says, it's related to how PHP namespaces work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with PHP 7 you can write:

```
use App\Entities\{Job, Category, City, JobType};
```

PHP 5 doesn't provide such a shortcut.

See http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php for other changes in PHP 7.

**Update:**

As @alister-bulman suggests in a comment below, the best you can do in PHP 5 is to declare the namespace of the classes you use (maybe with an alias that is shorter than its name) and then specify the names of the classes relative to this namespace.

For example:

```
use App\Entities as E;

$viewModel['categories']= E\Category::all();
$viewModel['cities'] = E\City::all();
$viewModel['jobTypes'] = E\JobType::all();
```

Comment: You can also declare `use App\Entities;`  and then use them in code as: `Entities\Category::all();`